# Parallelizing for loops using Dask (or other efficient way)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask

I have a function who takes xarray data set (similar to pandas multi-index) and uses 4 for loops embedded in each other to compute a new data array variable.

I wonder if there is a way I can use Dask to make this process faster, I'm quite new to this so I'm not sure.

The function looks like this:

```
def A_calc(data, thresh):

    A = np.zeros((len(data.time), len(data.lat), len(data.lon)))
    foo = xr.DataArray(A, coords=[data.time, data.lat, data.lon], 
                   dims=['time','lat', 'lon'])

    for t in tqdm(range(len(data.time))):
        for i in range(len(data.lat)):
            for j in range(2,len(data.lon)):
                for k in range(len(data.lev)):
                    if np.isnan(
                            data[dict(time=[t], lat=[i], lon=[j], lev=[k])].sigma_0.values):
                            foo[dict(time=[t], lat=[i], lon=[j])] = np.nan
                            break
                    elif abs(
                         data[dict(time=[t], lat=[i], lon=[j], lev=[k])].sigma_0.values
                         - data[dict(time=[t], lat=[i], lon=[j], lev=[1])].sigma_0.values) >= thresh:
                        foo[dict(time=[t], lat=[i], lon=[j])] = data.lev[k].values
                        break

    return foo
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Before going to distributed computing I would try to make the loop more efficient by using numba. They have option to run parallel for and support numy arrays.. Maybe worth you checking them out ?

Comment: Do you mind to produce an [mcve](/help/mcve)? In particular the input and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

As is said in the comments, Python for loops are slow.  Typically the first step to accelerating code like to this is to either ...

1. Find some clever way to write all of this as a vectorized numpy expression, without Python for loops
2. Use Numba